# App crashed while playing and recording RTSP feeds using MobileVLC Kit

Tags: ios, swift

I have developed an app for iPad Device. I am using **startRecordingAtPath:(NSString *)path** and **stopRecording()** to record the video in my App's Document directory. However app got crashed sometimes after 10-15 mins and sometimes after an hour of recording.
I need some suggestions so that I can debug this issue.

Added Crashlytics to find out the issues. However, I am not getting error in crashlytics. I need suggestion what else I should try or any other player to play RTSP feeds.

Please find code for reference:

```
func loadVideo(from url: URL) {
        
        //print("loadVideo from: \(url)")
        videoURL = url
        isStopped = false
        
        let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
        media.addOption("--network-caching:60000")
        media.addOption("--rtsp-tcp:true")
 
        mediaPlayer.libraryInstance.debugLogging = true
        mediaPlayer.libraryInstance.debugLoggingLevel = 2
        mediaPlayer.media = media
        isMuted = false
        mediaPlayer.play()
        
        self.redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder()
    }


func startRecording(at folderName: String) 
{
        
        //let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let DocumentDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
        let DirPath = DocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folderName)
        do
        {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: DirPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
        
        let videoPath = DirPath?.path
        
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("Run on background thread")
            _ = self.mediaPlayer.startRecording(atPath: videoPath)
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added code for reference. Please let me know if require to add more details